# MIssing all appearance settings except "Style"

Tags: 22.04, settings

After I updated my ubuntu to 22.04 i can't set dock position and other settings, as it's not presented in "Appearance" settings. The only setting I have there is "Style". So i want to know is there is possibility to bring all the settings back. [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install -y gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

brings it back.